# Converting a string to a condition in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, boolean, conditional-statements

I actually have a string called "cond". This is the content of that string:

```
"20 < 50"
```

I would like to insert it into a condition like this: (example)

```
if 20 < 50
return "Hello"
```

But that condition is a string, so I can't write this:

```
if cond
return "Hello"
```

So I would like to know if it is possible to convert a string to a condition to set in an "if" condition. And if it is possible, how can I do it ?

Thank you.

Comment: using eval would work but I imagine there's a better way to do it -- however that better way may lie in the structure of your program overall.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001390) might just be your friend here:

```
>> eval('20 < 50')
=> true
```

However, `eval` will execute the arbitrary code inside its argument; you should be sure that your `cond` can't contain anything detrimental to your system's health!

Answer (score 1):

One alternative to using eval is perhaps to write an evaluator (or use/modify an existing one, like [this one by Sterling Camden](http://www.chipstips.com/?p=119)).

As is his code requires you to write lt, gt, eq, and so on, instead of <, >, ==, ... . As noted in a comment in calc.rb:

> ```
> # Equality and its clan (note we cannot use '==' or other two-character
> # non-word operators, because of the way we parse the string.  Non-word
> # characters come in one at a time.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the condition will always be basic like the example you provided, you can do this:

```
left, op, right = "20 < 50".split
cond = left.to_i.send(op.to_sym, right.to_i)
```